# What is the meaning of "all about" in these contexts?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the contexts:

> we really know what computers are all about.

or

> which is basically what general relativity is all about.

I searched the web but couldn't find anything. The phrase **be what something is all about** is defined on [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-what-something-is-all-about):

> to be the true purpose of or reason for something

But it doesn't make any sense. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "This is all about..." is sometimes used to imply that what matters  in a particular situation is not what is apparently happening on the surface but something else.

So, for example, when a candidate for high office is revealed as having done something silly as a young person, you might say "this is all about undermining his claim to be a wise statesman". Most of us did some stupid things when we were young. The revelation that this candidate did so, is therefore not really surprising, but the fact that it has been made public **now** tells us that this story is 'all about' something else.